# White screen appears on phone when I use AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, htc-hero

There's problem with HTC Hero and AndEngine's `BaseGameActivity`: when launched, there's only white screen, without any graphics like background and sprites. But I can see objects like lines (`org.anddev.andengine.entity.primitive.Line`) etc. and also I can tap on invisible buttons and my code is performing, but it's still white screen.

When I'm launch this app on other devices everything is ok.

Where is the problem?

Comment: do any errors show up in LogCat? sounds like a memory constraint issue to me - like your graphics are not being loaded. are you using power of 2 for your texture atlas?

Comment: That's a problem with HTC Hero: I can't launch my app right from Idea and also I can't see logs. But everything works right on other devices and yes, I'm using power of 2 for texture atlases.

Comment: it may be the case that "force-gpu-rendereing" is enabled, and that this is the reason for white screens. Check it out in Settings->DeveloperOptions->Force-GPU-Rendering

Comment: There's no option like "Force-GPU-Rendering", only "USB debugging", "Stop app via long press" etc.

Comment: You can use the command adb logcat. Try adding this line to your project: AndEngine.isDeviceSupported() , maybe it will say something interesting.

Comment: There's no AndEngine class, so "Cannot resolve symbol AndEngine" isn't very interesting. I tried to search `isDeviceSupported()` but "No occurences found in project"

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I must have missed your reply. There most certainly is AndEngine class and the method I mentioned. See the source on GitHub: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/AndEngine.java

Comment: Oh, I've used GLES1 version, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my TextureAtlases was too big for this phone and I have to use several smaller atlases.

Comment: Try to make sure you use the smallest number of TextureAtlases possible, using too many is very expensive and will have a negative effect on performance of your application.